# How do I change YUI Editor's fontsize button from a spinner to a select?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui-editor

I'm implementing YUI Editor (2.8.2rc1), and need the font size to be a dropdown menu, much like the font name.  It's a bonus if we can control the font sizes listed (12, 14, 16, 18, 24, 36).

Based on examples, I have the following, which does not work for two reasons:

1. It doesn't work - the button no longer changes the font size
2. It erases all other buttons

   ```
   var myConfig = {
       height: '300px',
       width: '600px',
       dompath: true,
       focusAtStart: true,
       toolbar: {
           buttons: [
               { type: 'select', label: '13', value: 'fontsize', disabled: true,
                   menu: [
                       { text: '12' },
                       { text: '14', checked: true },
                       { text: '16' },
                       { text: '18' },
                       { text: '24' },
                       { text: '36' }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
   };


   var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('editor', myConfig);
   ```

So... how do I change this button from a spinner to a dropdown without affecting the other buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YUI Editor does not natively support this.